# How to speed up this numba based decision tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning

In order to improve the performance of this code fragment, I have speeded up some code fragments by using the numba. However, a frustrating thing is that the performance of this decision tree is bad. For example, in the below code fragment, the performance of the decision tree is nearly 70 times slower than the implementation in Scikit-learn (220 ms vs 3 ms). Therefore, how can I achieve better performance by modifying this code?

````py
import time

import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.datasets import make_hastie_10_2
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier


class Node:
    def __init__(self, left, right, rule):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.feature = rule[0]
        self.threshold = rule[1]


class Leaf:
    def __init__(self, value):
        """
        `value` is an array of class probabilities if classifier is True, else
        the mean of the region
        """
        self.value = value


class DecisionTree(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(
            self,
            classifier=True,
            max_depth=None,
            n_feats=None,
            criterion="entropy",
            seed=None,
            regularized=False,
    ):
        """
        A decision tree model for regression and classification problems.

        Parameters
        ----------
        classifier : bool
            Whether to treat target values as categorical (classifier =
            True) or continuous (classifier = False). Default is True.
        max_depth: int or None
            The depth at which to stop growing the tree. If None, grow the tree
            until all leaves are pure. Default is None.
        n_feats : int
            Specifies the number of features to sample on each split. If None,
            use all features on each split. Default is None.
        criterion : {'mse', 'entropy', 'gini'}
            The error criterion to use when calculating splits. When
            `classifier` is False, valid entries are {'mse'}. When `classifier`
            is True, valid entries are {'entropy', 'gini'}. Default is
            'entropy'.
        seed : int or None
            Seed for the random number generator. Default is None.
        """
        if seed:
            np.random.seed(seed)

        self.depth = 0
        self.root = None

        self.n_feats = n_feats
        self.criterion = criterion
        self.classifier = classifier
        self.max_depth = max_depth if max_depth else np.inf

        self.factor = 1.2
        self.regularized = regularized
        self.feature_importances_ = None

        if not classifier and criterion in ["gini", "entropy"]:
            raise ValueError(
                "{} is a valid criterion only when classifier = True.".format(criterion)
            )
        if classifier and criterion == "mse":
            raise ValueError("`mse` is a valid criterion only when classifier = False.")

    def fit(self, X, Y):
        """
        Fit a binary decision tree to a dataset.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : :py:class:`ndarray <numpy.ndarray>` of shape `(N, M)`
            The training data of `N` examples, each with `M` features
        Y : :py:class:`ndarray <numpy.ndarray>` of shape `(N,)`
            An array of integer class labels for each example in `X` if
            self.classifier = True, otherwise the set of target values for
            each example in `X`.
        """
        self.n_classes = max(Y) + 1 if self.classifier else None
        self.feature_importances_ = np.zeros(X.shape[1])
        self.used_variables = np.zeros(X.shape[1])
        self.n_feats = X.shape[1] if not self.n_feats else min(self.n_feats, X.shape[1])
        self.root = self._grow(X, Y)
        self.feature_importances_ = self.feature_importances_ / np.sum(self.feature_importances_)

    def predict(self, X):
        """
        Use the trained decision tree to classify or predict the examples in `X`.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : :py:class:`ndarray <numpy.ndarray>` of shape `(N, M)`
            The training data of `N` examples, each with `M` features

        Returns
        -------
        preds : :py:class:`ndarray <numpy.ndarray>` of shape `(N,)`
            The integer class labels predicted for each example in `X` if
            self.classifier = True, otherwise the predicted target values.
        """
        return np.array([self._traverse(x, self.root) for x in X])

    def predict_class_probs(self, X):
        """
        Use the trained decision tree to return the class probabilities for the
        examples in `X`.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : :py:class:`ndarray <numpy.ndarray>` of shape `(N, M)`
            The training data of `N` examples, each with `M` features

        Returns
        -------
        preds : :py:class:`ndarray <numpy.ndarray>` of shape `(N, n_classes)`
            The class probabilities predicted for each example in `X`.
        """
        assert self.classifier, "`predict_class_probs` undefined for classifier = False"
        return np.array([self._traverse(x, self.root, prob=True) for x in X])

    def _grow(self, X, Y, cur_depth=0):
        # if all labels are the same, return a leaf
        if len(set(Y)) == 1:
            if self.classifier:
                prob = np.zeros(self.n_classes)
                prob[Y[0]] = 1.0
            return Leaf(prob) if self.classifier else Leaf(Y[0])

        # if we have reached max_depth, return a leaf
        if cur_depth >= self.max_depth:
            v = np.mean(Y, axis=0)
            if self.classifier:
                v = np.bincount(Y, minlength=self.n_classes) / len(Y)
            return Leaf(v)

        cur_depth += 1
        self.depth = max(self.depth, cur_depth)

        N, M = X.shape
        feat_idxs = np.random.choice(M, self.n_feats, replace=False)

        # greedily select the best split according to `criterion`
        feat, thresh, best_gain = _segment(self.criterion, self.regularized, self.used_variables, self.factor,
                                           X, Y, feat_idxs)
        self.feature_importances_[feat] += len(X) * best_gain
        self.used_variables[feat] = 1

        l = np.argwhere(X[:, feat] <= thresh).flatten()
        r = np.argwhere(X[:, feat] > thresh).flatten()

        # grow the children that result from the split
        left = self._grow(X[l, :], Y[l], cur_depth)
        right = self._grow(X[r, :], Y[r], cur_depth)
        return Node(left, right, (feat, thresh))

    def _traverse(self, X, node, prob=False):
        if isinstance(node, Leaf):
            if self.classifier:
                return node.value if prob else node.value.argmax()
            return node.value
        if X[node.feature] <= node.threshold:
            return self._traverse(X, node.left, prob)
        return self._traverse(X, node.right, prob)


@njit()
def _segment(criterion, regularized, used_variables, factor, X, Y, feat_idxs):
    """
    Find the optimal split rule (feature index and split threshold) for the
    data according to `self.criterion`.
    """
    best_gain = -np.inf
    split_idx, split_thresh = None, None
    for i in feat_idxs:
        vals = X[:, i]
        levels = np.unique(vals)
        thresholds = (levels[:-1] + levels[1:]) / 2 if len(levels) > 1 else levels
        gains = np.array([_impurity_gain(criterion, Y, t, vals) for t in thresholds])

        if regularized and used_variables[i]:
            gains = gains * factor

        if gains.max() > best_gain:
            split_idx = i
            best_gain = gains.max()
            split_thresh = thresholds[gains.argmax()]

    return split_idx, split_thresh, best_gain


@njit()
def _impurity_gain(criterion, Y, split_thresh, feat_values):
    """
    Compute the impurity gain associated with a given split.

    IG(split) = loss(parent) - weighted_avg[loss(left_child), loss(right_child)]
    """
    if criterion == "entropy":
        parent_loss = entropy(Y)
    elif criterion == "gini":
        parent_loss = gini(Y)
    elif criterion == "mse":
        parent_loss = mse(Y)
    else:
        raise Exception

    # generate split
    left = np.argwhere(feat_values <= split_thresh).flatten()
    right = np.argwhere(feat_values > split_thresh).flatten()

    if len(left) == 0 or len(right) == 0:
        return 0

    # compute the weighted avg. of the loss for the children
    n = len(Y)
    n_l, n_r = len(left), len(right)
    if criterion == "entropy":
        e_l, e_r = entropy(Y[left]), entropy(Y[right])
    elif criterion == "gini":
        e_l, e_r = gini(Y[left]), gini(Y[right])
    else:
        raise Exception

    child_loss = (n_l / n) * e_l + (n_r / n) * e_r

    # impurity gain is difference in loss before vs. after split
    ig = parent_loss - child_loss
    return ig


@njit()
def mse(y):
    """
    Mean squared error for decision tree (ie., mean) predictions
    """
    return np.mean((y - np.mean(y)) ** 2)


@njit()
def entropy(y):
    """
    Entropy of a label sequence
    """
    hist = np.bincount(y)
    ps = hist / np.sum(hist)
    # return -np.sum([p * np.log2(p) for p in ps if p > 0])
    return -np.array([p * np.log2(p) for p in ps if p > 0]).sum()


@njit()
def gini(y):
    """
    Gini impurity (local entropy) of a label sequence
    """
    hist = np.bincount(y)
    N = np.sum(hist)
    return 1 - np.array([(i / N) ** 2 for i in hist]).sum()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_samples = 1000
    X, y = make_hastie_10_2(n_samples=n_samples)
    y[y < 0] = 0
    X = X.astype(np.float)
    y = y.astype(np.int)
    test_size = 0.2
    print(X.shape)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size)

    ts = time.time()
    tree = DecisionTree(seed=0, criterion='gini', max_depth=3)
    tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print(accuracy_score(y_train, tree.predict(X_train)))
    print(accuracy_score(y_test, tree.predict(X_test)))
    te = time.time()
    print('%2.2f ms' % ((te - ts) * 1000))

    ts = time.time()
    tree = DecisionTree(seed=0, criterion='gini', max_depth=3)
    tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print(accuracy_score(y_train, tree.predict(X_train)))
    print(accuracy_score(y_test, tree.predict(X_test)))
    te = time.time()
    print('%2.2f ms' % ((te - ts) * 1000))

    ts = time.time()
    tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0, max_depth=3)
    tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print(accuracy_score(y_train, tree.predict(X_train)))
    print(accuracy_score(y_test, tree.predict(X_test)))
    te = time.time()
    print('%2.2f ms' % ((te - ts) * 1000))
```
````

Comment: Welcome to CR, please [edit] your title so that it only states what your code does and not what you would expect in a review. Also, try to give a better description of your what your code does  in the question body as your current description is a little broad

Comment: Please add more tags (ex scipy, numpy)